# Can I make it without times table memorization?

Tags: soft-question

I am 24 years old and I am planing to get into mathematics sense it is essential In science. I have big plans and Math is the very first thing I want to focus on.
I have very important question that won't let me rest. When I was young I didn't take math too seriously or school. I never memorized times table (multiple/divide). The rest I did on high-school and my scores were average of 80/100. Can I dive into mathematics without the times table in my memory?

Comment: Sorry but there's no short cut to math proficiency.  Go back to square one and don't move past any step until you have a reasonable grasp of it.  Otherwise you'll be what we call a sloppy or hack mathematician.  And you don't want that.

Comment: I disagree with the comments. You can definitely, in my opinion, perform well as a mathematician even if you start from your position.

Comment: Sure you can avoid to take math seriously to the age of 24 and then move on to harder math without ever boning up on the basics.  If you're a genius that will work.  So you "can" perform well in theory.  But most likely you won't.  Or if you want to just be a poser who has no solid foundation then you can just plow ahead fearlessly.  Lots and lots of people do math that way so you certainly can.  But few of them "perform well".

Comment: Thanks guys for comments. I don't want weak fundamental as i am well aware the effectiveness of solid ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The times table is a thing that you will require throughout your life, not only for studying mathematics or science but for day-to-day activities as well where there is the smallest bit of multiplication required.

As such, there is no compulsion for one to memorise the tables beforehand, but it helps a lot for doing complicated multiplications and for quick solution of elementary problems.... which is "widely regarded" as the signs of a *sound mathematician*.

So my advice would be that you mug up the time tables and do sums based on them. Believe me, if you work properly, in a month or so, the tables will be there in your head to stay forever. And after approximately $6$ months, you will notice that you do not have to recall or revise those tables at all. It will flow out of your pen like a stream of water whenever you start writing.

Comment: Thank you If you have some tips I could effectively learn the times table I would appreciate it.